# In C#, how to trigger the PropertyChanged event when an elements in a array gets modified

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, inotifypropertychanged

I have a array property, in which I want to notify whenever any elements of that array gets changed.

```
private double[] _OffsetAngles = new double[3];
public double[] OffsetAngles
    {
        get { return _OffsetAngles; }
        set
        {
            _OffsetAngles = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

if any of the elements of *OffsetAngles* gets changed, I want to get the notification. 
i.e. if I set OffsetAngles[1] = 20; //Trigger should happen.
if I set OffsetAngles[0] = 40; //Trigger should happen again.

Comment: Have you tried using an ObservableCollection? Or do you have to use an Array?

Comment: Yes, I have tried ObservableCollection as well. But for tat as well, if the elements gets changed, the event is not getting triggered.

Comment: I was trying to give you an answer and you down vote. I dont know why?

Comment: If you use `ObservableCollection<double>`, a bound collection-type property like the ItemsSource property of an ItemsControl will be notified. You will however not get a change notification for the OffsetAngles property itself, simply because it does not change when you add or remove elements to it. The collection instance doesn't change.

Comment: You may however attach a CollectionChanged event handler to the ObservableCollection that simply calls `NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(OffsetAngles))`

Comment: I haven't done any voting (up/down). I was checking your answer only! @AnkurShah

Comment: The most simple solution would be to assign a new array to the OffsetAngles property every time an element changes.

Comment: @Clemens But that solution is very inefficient I think, though it would definitely work.

Comment: @cmos How do you know that it is inefficient? OP hasn't told anything about what they are doing with the data. And the array has only three elements. I'd say any *other* solution than replacing it is less efficient.

Comment: @Clemens, Thanks for your answer! 
As you have mentioned, if the property is subscribed with CollectionChanged event 
(OffsetAngles.CollectionChanged += OffsetAngles_CollectionChanged;)

 then it notifies whenever any value of the elements gets changed. May be you can provide it as a answer. So that I can Up vote that.

Comment: @Pravin Be aware that this solution may still not trigger an update on the target property of a Binding. A bound dependency property usually ignores a change notification when the property does not actually have a new value.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine that you are not using double but some class. And then that the filed of that class has changed. Should the array raise property changed? Surely not. So there are multiple solutions that you may consider:

- use `ObservableCollection` and its `SetItem` method
- use `ObservableCollection` and instead of assigning value remove and insert the value
- instead of double use some class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and when the dobule changes raise this event, it should be right approach if the purpose is data binding
- recreate the `Array` each time (cumbersome and inefficient but still works)

Comment: "recreate the Array each time" I wouldn't call that *cumbersome and inefficient*. Instead, it may be the only working solution, since a dependency property bound to OffsetAngles may ignore any change notification unless the property actually has a new value, i.e. a new array instance.

Answer (score 0):

So as others have mentioned, in your case you fire the NotifyPropertyChanged() when the array itself is changed, not any element of the array.

If you want the elements to be able to fire the event you would have to implement a class like:

```
public class NotifyingData<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    private T _Data;
    public T Data
    {
        get { return _Data; }
        set { _Data = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(); }
    }
}
```

and then populate your array with that class:

```
_OffsetAngles[0] = new NotifyingData<double> { Data = 10 };
```

I don't have access to VS right now, so there might be some errors, but this should be the right concept for you.

Comment: This is a good answer.  i would just add that you need to connect the **PropertyChanged** event for each array member to a single event handler.  You can do this in a **foreach** loop

Comment: This is the third post here that does not answer the question. How would this fire a change notification for OffsetAngles?

Answer (score -1):

This example shows how to create and bind to a collection that derives from the ObservableCollection class, which is a collection class that provides notifications when items get added or removed.

```
public class NameList : ObservableCollection<PersonName>  
{  
    public NameList() : base()  
    {  
        Add(new PersonName("Willa", "Cather"));  
        Add(new PersonName("Isak", "Dinesen"));  
        Add(new PersonName("Victor", "Hugo"));  
        Add(new PersonName("Jules", "Verne"));  
    }  
  }  

  public class PersonName  
  {  
      private string firstName;  
      private string lastName;  

      public PersonName(string first, string last)  
      {  
          this.firstName = first;  
          this.lastName = last;  
      }  

      public string FirstName  
      {  
          get { return firstName; }  
          set { firstName = value; }  
      }  

      public string LastName  
      {  
          get { return lastName; }  
          set { lastName = value; }  
      }  
  }
```

The objects in your collection must satisfy the requirements described in the Binding Sources Overview. In particular, if you are using OneWay or TwoWay (for example, you want your UI to update when the source properties change dynamically), you must implement a suitable property changed notification mechanism such as the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection

Comment: This post does not answer the question. It misses the important point that OP is asking for a change notification of their OffsetAngles property when elements are added, removed or set. ObservableCollection won't magically do that.

Comment: if this is not answer please let know your answer?

Comment: See the explanation in my comments

Comment: As a note, if you introduce an item class like your PersonName class, this should typically also implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface. This is however irrelevant, because OP is asking about a collection of primitives, i.e. `double`.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue a while ago. I had to update a DataTable whenever the data changed and that's how I solved it on my program :

```
public ObservableCollection<KeyStroke> keyList = new ObservableCollection<KeyStroke>();
public class KeyStroke : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // KeyStroke class storing data about each key and how many types it received
    private int id;
    private int numPress;
    public KeyStroke(int id, int numPress)
    {
        Id = id;
        NumPress = numPress;
    }
    public int Id
    {
        get => id;
        set
        {
            id = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Id");
        }
    }
    public int NumPress
    {
        get { return this.numPress; }
        set
        {
            this.numPress = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NumPress");
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged; //This handle the propertyChanged
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); //This is the WPF code for the DataGrid but you can replace it by whatever you need
    }
}
```

This should help you. You can also put conditions inside the getter/setters of the properties but I think it's not really pretty

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is asking for how to get a change notification for the collection property, not for a property of a collection element. Besides that the code comment `This is the WPF code for the DataGrid but you can replace it by whatever you need` makes no sense at all. When you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface, you should of course invoke the PropertyChanged event, and not do anything else.